# Active Directory Powershell to fixed width txt file

Tags: powershell

Trying to export 4 objects from Ad to a fixed-width txt file with no header.

I need the following columns to be the width that follows.

```
Employee ID    10 
Work Phone      10
Work Phone Extension    5
Work Email Address      50
User ID             20
```

The following gives me the best output, but doesn't size the columns the way I need. I have been digging around, and think what I need is a bit beyond what I'm comfortable with.

I'm not sure if i need to export with export-csv and then import that into reformat or if I can do out-file directly.

```
$DateTime = Get-Date -f "yyyyMMdd"

#// Set CSV file name
$CSVFile = "d:\scripts\workday\int002_"+$DateTime+".txt"

Get-ADGroup -Filter {(name -like "*Group Name*")} `
    | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | Where { $_.objectClass -eq "user" } `
    | Get-ADUser -properties * | where {$_.enabled -eq $true} `
    | select employeeid,telephoneNumber,mail,sAMAccountName  -unique | FT employeeid,telephoneNumber,mail,sAMAccountName -hidetableheaders -autosize | out-file $CSVFile
```

Sample Output:

```
8855      2122445710     xxxry.michalsen@companydomain.com                 michalsenm
```

Comment: Please note that the [edit] UI has built-in formatting which you can use to fix the strange formatting the code has in this question.

Comment: What happened with the `Work Phone Extension` in your sample output?

Comment: Sorry, don't need the work phone extension extracted. I forgot to remove it from the exported information.

Comment: Why do you require fixed width output? Wouldn't a CSV output file be easier?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to do it manually...

```
$result = foreach($user in $users) {
    $user.employeeid.PadRight(10),
    $user.telephoneNumber.PadRight(10),
    $user.mail.PadRight(50),
    $user.sAMAccountName.PadRight(20) -join ' '
}

$result | Out-File $CSVFile
```

A revised version that also works if the property is not a string:

```
$result = foreach($user in $users) {
    '{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-50}{3,-20}' -f
        $user.employeeid,
        $user.telephoneNumber,
        $user.mail,
        $user.sAMAccountName
}

$result | Out-File $CSVFile
```

Comment: Padding wouldn't shorten possibly too long entries, this requieres also a `.Substring(0,width)` and padding is IMO easier done with a `-format` operator for all properties. => `"{0,10}{1,10}{2,5}{3,-50}{4,-20}" -f $user.employeeid, ...`

Comment: I'm not sure he wants it to be shortened. A shortened email is no good.

Comment: Well shortened to the width he provides, a fixed width record format broken seems even less usefull.

Comment: Shouldn't need anything shortened or truncated. Everything I output should fit in each column.

Comment: After looking, the PadRight may be all I need. Just need to play with the code to get it working properly. Currently it is outputting an empty file.

Comment: Okay, I have been playing with Palasen's padright options, I haven't gotten it to work properly, the console shows but not spaced, and the outfile is empty. Maybe Lotpings solution will work, but I am having trouble rapping my head around where in my coding any of this would go and still have it out-file properly.

Comment: I've updated with a new version. LotPings has a point... This version also works, if the property is not a string (missing the Pad member).

Comment: @Palansen where is the $user and $users string coming from?